# Searching a word from a database in my Java app

Tags: java, sql

I have a quizzes table where I store the name of the test and the question, and I want the user(teacher) to enter a word in a Jtextfield, and the program to show all the questions which contain the given word. I tried using the LIKE operator from SQL, it produces no error but also doesn't show any output.

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM quizzes WHERE testName =\"" + 
testName + "\" AND question LIKE '%\""+ word + "\"%';");
```

Have I written something wrong?

Comment: Could you give an example of you data (specifically the `testName` and `question` columns in `quizzes`) as well as potential `testName` and `word` input? Your sql looks correct - as there are no warnings or errors. If it is not producing the desired results, it probably is not finding anything.

Comment: please use prepared statements, the way you're building your query is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix the following things:

- Try single quotes (not double quotes) in varchar equality.
- Remove the double quotes in the LIKE operator.
- Remove the semi colon at the end.

It should look like:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM quizzes WHERE testName ='" + 
  testName + "' AND question LIKE '%"+ word + "%'");
```

Comment: thank you, it works this way. But why do I have to remove the semicolon? I thought it was advised to use it. And why does it not work with the double quotes as I wrote them initially? My teacher showed me that and it works for the other statements.

Comment: When you are interactively typing a SQL, then yeah, use the semicolon to separate multiple statements. Here, however, you are running one at a time so there's no need for a statement separator. The semicolon is not part of SQL but it's an implementation detail of your database. SQL Server (for example) uses `GO` instead.

Comment: The `like` operator uses the wildcards `%` and `_` to match varchars. Anything else is treated as part of the string you want to search. If you added the extra double quotes, the `like` operator would look for them too... and would find nothing (most likely).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `%` inside quotations.